# Adding Conditional Behavior to Camel Twitter Consumer Results

Tags: java, twitter, apache-camel

Using Apache Camel Twitter component, my program is retrieving the status updates from a particular user. I'm using the consumer component.

One request (producerTemplate.send()) will return potentially multiple exchanges (one per Status).

My question- is there a way I can add some conditional logic based on the number of exchanges received using the Java DSL?

Is something like the following pseudocode possible?

```
from("twitter://user...")
    .choice()
        .when(simple("${exchanges.size()} >= 15"))
            .<do something here>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current twitter doesn't support to send a exchange group to the next processor, so your DSL doesn't work. But if you want to process the exchange in a group, you can use [aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) to do the job.